# Make text in image thinner for OCR

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I'm making an automated text recognition script with Python on Ubuntu.

I'm using [Gocr](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/) and the recognition render is too low.

Exemple:

[image]

Output: `_O4_4E34E_4_O4_`

I suppose that the type in the image is too bold, so I'm asking if there is a way to make it thinner using an python library or a linux command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably will need to apply a morphological operation like "erosion" on your image, e.g by using OpenCV. This will make structures thinner. To the cost of the quality, though.

Look here: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html

Comment: You're welcome! Did it improve the recognition rate?